# Google Earth Engine FeatureCollection getDownloadURL returns empty CSV

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google, download

I am trying to create a link that lets me or users of my app download a feature collection as a CSV directly from the map. However, when using ee.FeatureCollection.getDownloadURL, the csv that it downloads is always empty. When I print the feature collection to the screen there are features and attributes there. Any ideas as to why it's outputting an empty CSV?

Here is the part of my script that is outputting the download url:

```
  var output_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(leng.map(function(x){
    var dict = {class_name: to.get(x), class_area: class_areas_results.get(x), tree_cover_loss_area: tcl_results.get(x), tree_cover_gain_area: tc_gain_results.get(x), 
    avg_tree_area: avg_tree_area_results.get(x), tcd_00: tcd_00_results.get(x), tcd_10: tcd_10_results.get(x)};
    var feature = ee.Feature(null, dict);
    return feature;
  }));

  var download = (ui.Label('Download').setUrl((ee.FeatureCollection(output_fc).getDownloadURL({
    format: 'CSV',
    filename: 'changeAreas'
  }))))

  panel.add(download)

  print(output_fc)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the error as leng was not found. But have you tried providing column names with *selectors* option in getDownloadURL? it can be `.getDownloadURL({
    format: 'CSV',
    filename: 'changeAreas',
    selectors: ee.FeatureCollection(output_fc).first().propertyNames().getInfo()
  }))));` assuming your feature collection is consistent with its properties.

Comment: Thank you SO much! That worked! Here is the link to my app if you are interested! It calculates areas of land use change between time periods and calculates the areas of tree cover loss within each class, then lets you download as a csv.

https://thailynnmunroe.users.earthengine.app/view/getcountyareasforghg